# How to split data in html with php line by line?

Tags: php, html

I am looking to stop using "br" in my code, but I cannot line by line after I have removed "br" tag in my coding. Why I want to remove "br"? Because inside the item data through the ecommerce online shopping website, if I use "br"tag. It show me error. So that I must remove the "br" tag.

Here is the code to remove br in html that I currently have:

```
$product_description = strip_tags($product_description);
echo "$product_description";
```

This would give me an output of(not line by line):

```
1 unit of 3M 3200, individual packagingRespirator only, not including 
cartridge or filterMaterial: ThermoplasticKOSHA StandardLow profile design 
allows a wide field of visionLightweight makes long period of wear 
bearableSoft, elastomeric face-fit secures a lasting comfortUnique easy to 
don/doff strap systemThe 3M™ Reusable Half Face Mask Respirator 3200. 
Features include: An elastomeric face seal, M/L in size, it is a compact 
and lightweight half mask that offers an economical solution for a range 
of applications
```

Actually I want the output like each data line by line below:

```
1 unit of 3M 3200, individual packaging
Respirator only, not including cartridge or filter
Material: Thermoplastic
KOSHA Standard
Low profile design allows a wide field of vision
Lightweight makes long period of wear bearable
Soft, elastomeric face-fit secures a lasting comfort
Unique easy to don/doff strap system
The 3M™ Reusable Half Face Mask Respirator 3200. Features include: An 
elastomeric face seal, M/L in size, it is a compact and lightweight half 
mask that offers an economical solution for a range of applications
```

Hope someone can help me solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: You should save line break characters into database and convert them to `<br>` when output to html.

Comment: its a description, line breaks makes sense, you should leave them and fix the 'error'

Comment: can convert using li class?

Comment: Your question completely circumvent the actual problem. What you are asking us is how can I drive a car with square wheels, instead of asking how can I fix my broken tires. I'm quite sure this problem, even if you manage to go round it, will come back a second and a third time to bite you.